# The Groovy way to do value matching?

Tags: groovy

Just wonder **groovy** way to do value matching with default like this?

```
if(params.max != 10 && params.max != 20 && params.max != 30){
    params.max = 10
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
params.max = [10, 20, 30].contains(params.max)) ? params.max : 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Elvis operator (?:) which is useful in this kind of situation.  It returns the 2nd value if the first value is null:

```
params.max = [10, 20, 30].find{ it == params.max } ?: 10
```